# Phonegap to Native iOS Without Resubmission

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, phonegap, publishing

I have a Phonegap app that is published on the App Store that I would like converted to native iOS. I'm in the process of redeveloping the app in Swift and once I am done, will I be able to push it as an update? Or will I have to republish the whole app again?

I don't want my current user base to have to re-download and reconfigure the app all over again.

I apologize if this question has been asked before but I was not able to find any answers.

Comment: They will get the new app as an update, but about the configure part, if they have some local configuration (like localStorage or a localDB) then that won't be restored, you will have to do some migration path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's signed with the same certificates it will be presented as an update